# Delay automated email like receipts

Tags: civicontribute, civimail, receipts

Is there a way I can delay when a automated E-Mail is sent.
For Example - I would like the receipt email when one submits a contribution to be delayed by a few hours. 
Thank you

Comment: I have been trying it with the suggested answer below. I do not see any actions for "delay receipt." I have tried: trigger "Contribution Add", action "Send Email". That only allows me to select the User-Driven Messages and not System Workflow Messages. I tried to make a User-Driven Message but it does not seem to like smarties (I copied and pasted the default online receipt). I have a piece of custom data that is not being written to the table in time to be included on the System Workflow Online Receipt so I want to build a a delayed receipt so it can include that piece of information.

Comment: I now have it sending me an email but it does not include the donation data. I assume that it is because the User-Driven Messages work flow is not getting the contribution information from the CiviRule trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this extension by CiviCoop: CiviRules. You can do exactly that -> delayed Actions: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules

Comment: Thank you.
Do I have to create my own action? I do not see an option to delay the E-Mail receipt there.

Comment: No need to create your own action -> you (likely) just need to also add CiviCoop’s Email API extension.

Comment: I see it now (did not have the email API extension enabled. Will it automatically send the receipt? Or do I need to make a whole template? Also will it automatically update the contribution as "receipt sent"?

Comment: Does this just delay the email being sent or does it also delay the creation of the receipt attached to said email?